# can I include a file with class in another class?

Tags: php

```
file.php

class file{
    function include_file($file_name){
        include($file_name);
    }
}

$file = new file;
$file->include_file('content.php');

----------------------------------
content.php

include('content_class.php');
$content = new content;
switch($option){
    case 'a':
        $content->table_list($option);
    break;
}

----------------------------------
content_class.php
class content{
    function table_list($option){
        echo 'table list for option : '.$option;
    }
}
```

I've tested those code and it give the result
// table list for option : a

but i want to know are those class above run in valid way of OOP class ? since class content running inside class file because it was included via content.php

i'm still new with OOP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm cringing when I see a class wrapper for include().

Comment: Yes, classes-definitions have no scope, so they'll always be reachable. You might want to `require_once` your class definitions rather them `include` them though, or you might run into duplicate definition errors.

Comment: I read it as: 'can I include a classfile in another class, and can I use this class from that point on'. Might be mistaken though.

Comment: @FinalForm :), that's why i want to know are those a valid method of OOP Class ? since it give me the correct results.

Comment: @froditus, if you want to easily include several files, either put them all at the top of a common include, or use lazy loading.

Comment: @Wrikken, thanks for point it right. Yes that was what i meant. :) I've updated my question title

Comment: @froditus: ack, this can and will work, but you might want to check out `__autoload` or even better the improved `spl_autoload_register`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in content.php, assuming that `$option` is set in previous lines of code, that the `switch` block should look like this:

```
switch ($option) {
    case 'a':
        $content->table_list($option);
        break;
}
```

Since `table_list` is a member of the class `content`. otherwise, I believe that the classes as declared above are valid. I am not sure about including files in the middle of a class in *file.php*, though. If nothing else, it probably isn't doing you any favors.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title:  **Yes, classes can be defined in basically any scope, and includes can be nested inside functions.**  So, defining the `content` class where you have done it is perfectly valid.

That said, three things about the code:

**1)** You are referencing `table_list` as a variable* (`$table_list`) instead of method on the `content` object:

```
switch($option){
    case 'a':
        $content->table_list($option);
    break;
}
```

**2)** When you include a file from inside a method (in this case, the `$file->include_file` method), the execution is in the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of that method.  That means that `$option` in the line `switch($option)` will be undefined (since it isn't defined anywhere in this script).  You may need to pull it in from a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), from a parameter passed to the original method, or using the `global` keyword:

```
global $option;
switch($option){ ...
```

**3)**: If you are just going to pass `$option` to the method, you probably don't need the switch statement, though maybe your example is just oversimplified.

```
global $option;
$content->table_list($option);
```

Lastly, the examples are obviously very simple classes, so I can't really judge whether they are good objects, but right now they aren't serving any purpose as objects since they have no [members](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).  (Therefore, they are the same as [plain old functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), right now — in other words, they don't need any object scope.)

---

<sup>* Note that in PHP this is not a syntax error.  Instead, it evaluates the *value* of `$table_list` and then tries to call a function by that name.  If `$table_list` contained "a", it would try to call `a()`.</sup>

Comment: yes.., i've update the typo. it supposed to be $content->table_list($option)